# Javascript file not loading to browser

Tags: javascript

i have a problem where for some reason my .js file is not loaded to browser, when other files are. The problem is that the file that should be loaded is important for my "site" to work. Heres code:

```
var viewModel = new PeopleTableViewModel({ 
// uncaught reference error      Peopetable view model is not defined
pageSize: 25,
current: data.length,
context: document.getElementById('table')
});

var comparator = new Comparators();

function init() {
viewModel.next();
}
```

Heres my HTML :

```
    <div id="table"></div>

    <button onclick="viewModel.prev()">PREV</button>
    <button onclick="viewModel.next()">NEXT</button>


    <script type="application/javascript" src="scripts/DATA.js"></script>
    <script type="application/javascript" src="scripts/Comparators.js"></script>
    <script type="application/javascript" scr="scripts/PeopleTableViewModel.js"></script>
    <script type="application/javascript" src="scripts/ListOfPeople.js"></script>
    <script type="application/javascript" src="scripts/scripts.js"></script>
    <script type="application/javascript" src="scripts/Person.js"></script>

</body>
```

And PeopleTableViewModel.js:

```
function PeopleTableViewModel(config) {
  var self = this;
  self.people = new ListOfPeople();
  self.currentPage = 0;
  self.pageSize = config.pageSize;
  self.context = config.context;

  self.next = function() {
    //alert('kliknąłeś następny');
    self.people.clear();
    var begin = (self.currentPage) * self.pageSize;
    var end = (self.currentPage + 1) * self.pageSize;
    getData(begin, end);
    self.currentPage++;
    self.context.innerHTML = self.people.toTable();
  }
  self.prev = function() {
    //alert('kliknąłeś poprzedi');
    self.people.clear();
    if (self.currentPage - 1 >= 0) {
      self.currentPage--;
    }
    var begin = (self.currentPage) * self.pageSize;
    var end = (self.currentPage + 1) * self.pageSize;
    getData(begin, end);
    self.context.innerHTML = self.people.toTable();
  }

  self.sort = function(comparer) {
    data.sort(comparer);
    self.currentPage = 0;
    self.next();
  }

  var getData = function(begin, end) {
    if (end > data.length) {
      end = data.length;
    }
    if (begin < 0) {
      begin = 0;
    }
    for (var i = begin; i < end; i += 1) {
      self.people.addPerson(data[i]);
    }
  }
}
```

Thank you for taking time on my issue !

Comment: Have you tried by including the file using `script` tag?

Comment: Where is the code at the top executed? Make sure PeopleTableViewModel.js is being included before that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You made a mistake in the html markup.

```
<script type="application/javascript" scr="scripts/PeopleTableViewModel.js"></script>
```

instead of

```
<script type="application/javascript" src="scripts/PeopleTableViewModel.js"></script>
```